# Crontab help with automatically running a script

Tags: cron

sorry if this is a duplicate, but I wanted to check that I am in fact using crontab correctly. I want to run a script every 10 minutes and to do this I put `10 * * * * ~/autokill` in crontab -e without the ''s.
If I am doing this wrong, please let me know as I don't think it's working.

Comment: Hint: Where do you believe the `~` points to inside a script that is run by user root?

Comment: Change `~/autokill` to `/home/yourname/autokill` because cron demands full path names.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and tell you the results in around 10 mins.